# Selenium - One specific element is only clicked in debug mode

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a large test and at one point I click on an element that opens a new page.

On that page, I do a check for a specific button and if it is present it should be clicked.

The problem is it only gets clicked when I debug my test and not when I run it.

I have added waits in the test but the button is still not clicked.

Any ideas?

Comment: what framework are you using, cucumber-jvm? Please share the code. How do you expect someone to help without code here?

Comment: I am using Serenity with JUnit. But managed to solve the issue

Comment: please share the resolution or close the question

Comment: Strangely enough the solution for me was to add a wait after I clicked the element

Comment: That's not a good solution...rather use something like waituntil